# Beautifulsoup getting span label-value content pairs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract "Slutrengøring alm. (DKK 750,00)DKK" from this HTML:

```
<div id="bookingpartoptionalitems" class="paddingLeft paddingRight">
<div class="title paddingTop">Valgfrie tilkøb:</div>
<div class="dots dotsHeight alignment-line">
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-controlarea"><span class="control-area checkboxArea paddingRight negMarginTop">  <input id="fvF3625F31BE0A4F0A8DCD3F59477CD535" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-namearea"><span class="BookingDataItemName paddingRight"><label for="fvF3625F31BE0A4F0A8DCD3F59477CD535">Håndklæder (leje)</label> <span class="BookingDataItemUnitPrice">(<span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">112,00</span>)</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"><span class="BookingDataItemTotalPrice paddingLeft"><span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">0,00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="dots dotsHeight alignment-line">
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-controlarea"><span class="control-area checkboxArea paddingRight negMarginTop"><input id="fvC7796D75FE6D429187EB9705D87B0289" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-namearea"><span class="BookingDataItemName paddingRight"><label for="fvC7796D75FE6D429187EB9705D87B0289">Slutrengøring alm.</label> <span class="BookingDataItemUnitPrice">(<span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">750,00</span>)</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"><span class="BookingDataItemTotalPrice paddingLeft"><span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">0,00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="dots dotsHeight alignment-line">
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-controlarea"><span class="control-area checkboxArea paddingRight negMarginTop"><input id="fv64F0EAE9857F4D219BB3EDE247ED6EA8" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-namearea"><span class="BookingDataItemName paddingRight"><label for="fv64F0EAE9857F4D219BB3EDE247ED6EA8">Leje Sengelinnede </label> <span class="BookingDataItemUnitPrice">(<span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">112,00</span>)</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"><span class="BookingDataItemTotalPrice paddingLeft"><span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">0,00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="dots dotsHeight alignment-line last-item">
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-controlarea"><span class="control-area checkboxArea paddingRight negMarginTop"><input id="fvF418ABD7452A45C2B22F98AE5348B13F" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container optional-items-namearea"><span class="BookingDataItemName paddingRight"><label for="fvF418ABD7452A45C2B22F98AE5348B13F">Internet</label> <span class="BookingDataItemUnitPrice">(<span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">149,00</span>)</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"><span class="BookingDataItemTotalPrice paddingLeft"><span class="currency">DKK</span> <span class="value">0,00</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="alignment-container"></div>
</div>
```

I tried `bsObj.select("#bookingpartoptionalitems label")` which outputs:

```
[<label for="fvEC6D027BF92643FB915F1B3D40C2ADAC">Senget▒jspakke</label>, <label for="fv4C0AAC0318FC408C9D42A6EC152AE878">Barnestol</label>, <label for="fv1B2B8ADFBAA74CE094B55514FF02674F">Barneseng</label>, <label for="fvCA3BB2602AD44C07A1F38B430A73D699">Ekstra Fryser (100L) inkl. levering</label>, <label for="fv7F8D503E6BE84A78A54C92001C195DCA">Levering/afhentning tilk▒bte varer</label>, <label for="fv62D7E7BCC1914FBB82802AF9A0D10B27">Tr▒kvogn</label>, <label for="fvF3D92DC8F8BC43F48525A9D032A6130F">Afbestillingsforsikring (ingen selvrisiko)</label>, <label for="fv3CED5B2C3ADC4309A3B7EEA11BBC924D">Kombiforsikring (ingen selvrisiko)</label>, <label for="fv5BC0B453EA5A42E19BFCAC87739CC515">Beach Bowl Key2Activity</label>]
```

and `bsObj.select("#bookingpartoptionalitems .value")` which outputs:

```
[<span class="value">105,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">300,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">140,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">125,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">243,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">360,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>, <span class="value">119,00</span>, <span class="value">0,00</span>]
```

Is there are a way to get the label and value in pairs. The label `for="fvC7796D75FE6D429187EB9705D87B0289"` cannot be used as it seems to be generated dynamically.

I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get all the label-value pairs? Well one way is that you could run the two queries you have already tried and combine the data, since I believe it will be in order. Or you could do something like this:

```
items = bsObj.find_all('div', class_='optional-items-namearea')

for item in items:
    print(item.label.get_text(), item.find('span', class_='value').get_text())
```

This would find all the items with the class `"optional-items-namearea"`, and then you iterate over them and extract the text inside label. For value you need to use find since it is inside another element.

For your example data the output would be:

```
Håndklæder (leje) 112,00
Slutrengøring alm. 750,00
Leje Sengelinnede  112,00
Internet 149,00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
divs = soup.find_all(class_="alignment-container optional-items-namearea")

for div in divs:
    pair = div.get_text(strip=True)
    print(pair)
```

out:

```
Håndklæder (leje)(DKK112,00)
Slutrengøring alm.(DKK750,00)
Leje Sengelinnede(DKK112,00)
Internet(DKK149,00)
```